# Intellij SBT Timeout errors

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm new to Scala with SBT and I'm trying to figure out the new IntelliJIDE.

When I follow the tutorial for setting up the below shows up:

> ERRORS Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect
>   url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/sbt-0.13.13.pom
>   Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect
>   url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/sbt-0.13.13.jar
>   Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect
>   url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/ivys/ivy.xml
>   Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect
>   url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/ivys/ivy.xml

After adding the below artifact its still the same

[Artifact added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVHHO.png)

Answer (score 0):

sbt artifact does not exist on the repos that are being accessed.

Add the following repository and then it will be able to fetch sbt:

```
https://repo.lightbend.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/
```